# Подписка/отписка пользователя VK

Tags: vkontakte-api

Не могу найти api vk, что бы сделать реакцию бота на подписку/отписку пользователя сообщества. Какой метод использовать?

Answer (score 1):

У ВКонтакте есть [Callback API для сообществ](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api). Вас интересуют события
**group_join** и **group_leave**.

> Чтобы начать использовать Callback API, подключите свой сервер в
>   настройках сообщества и выберите типы событий, данные о которых
>   требуется получать (например, новые комментарии и новые фотографии).
>   Когда в сообществе произойдет событие выбранного типа, ВКонтакте
>   отправит на Ваш сервер запрос в формате JSON с основной информацией об
>   объекте, вызвавшем событие (например, добавленный комментарий).

Answer (score 0):

Из документации:

> 3. События
>      При клике на кнопку "Подписаться"
>
> виджет передаёт событие **widgets.groups.joined**. Если участник покидает сообщество с помощью виджета, передается событие **widgets.groups.leaved**. Вы можете обрабатывать эти события, используя **VK.Observer**.

Может быть, оно?

Comment: Не совсем. Нужно без вилжета. То есть пользователь подписывается и от бота приходит сообщение (Предпологаб, что рассылка сообщений уже разрешена).

Comment: Что бы было как в этой группе https://vk.com/okunderstand